# Проблема с SaveChanges() в PostgreSql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

При попытке сохранить данные в таблицу **OrderDetail** базы данных, вылезает ошибка *"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."*. Внутреннее исключение:PostgresException: 23503: INSERT или UPDATE в таблице "OrderDetail" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "FK_OrderDetail_Order_OrderId".* В первую таблицу **Order** все хорошо сохраняется. Все совпадает с базой. База данных PostgreSql.Код:

```
public void CreateOrder(Order order)
        {
            var suf = appDBContent.Users.Where(e => e.Email == "admin");
            foreach (var el in suf)
            {
                var order1 = new Order()
                {
                    Name_client = el.UserName,
                    Surname = el.Surname,
                    Phone = el.Phone,
                    Mail = el.Email,
                    Adress = el.Adress,
                    OrderTime = DateTime.Now
                };
                appDBContent.Order.Add(order1);
            }
            appDBContent.SaveChanges();

            var items = cart.ListBookItems;
            foreach (var el in items)
            {
                var orderdetail = new OrderDetail()
                {
                    BookId = el.book.Id,
                    OrderId = order.Id
                };
                appDBContent.OrderDetail.Add(orderdetail);
            }
            appDBContent.SaveChanges(); //Ошибка вылезает в этом месте
        }
```

Если в foreach сделать так, то все правильно работает:

```
foreach (var el in suf)
            {
                order.Name_client = el.UserName;
                order.Surname = el.Surname;
                order.Phone = el.Phone;
                order.Mail = el.Email;
                order.Adress = el.Adress;
                order.OrderTime = DateTime.Now;
                appDBContent.Order.Add(order);
            }
```

Comment: ошибка говорит, что ты пытаешься установить orderId которого нет в таблице Orders - проверяй что за данные тебе приходят

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо!